# Why is beaucoup followed by "de" only, but plupart is followed by du/de la/des ?

Tags: grammaire, articles

I've noticed in my reading that *plupart* doesn't obey the same rule as *beaucoup* and other words, where *de la/du/des/de l'* becomes *de*.

For instance, it's "beaucoup de temps" but *la plupart du temps.*

Why is that? Does *plupart* not count as an "amount modifier," so to speak?

It sort of makes sense if I translate literally to English-- "most of *the* time", "a lot *of* time," but I'm not sure if it's so simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say very different things when you say "*beaucoup de temps*" and "*la plupart du temps*".

Like you said it's equivalent to "a lot *of* time" vs "most *of the* time":

when you say "*beaucoup de temps*" you're counting **units** of time, or rather gauging because it's uncountable.

When you say "*la plupart du temps*" (or "*tout le temps*"), you're expressing **fractions** of *the* time as a whole.

It's the same difference between "*a lot of sugar*" and "*most of the cake*". It's completely different things you're measuring.

Comment: Agreed. Also, consider the more syntactically exact parallel of a container vs. a fraction: "la boîte de riz" vs. "la plupart du riz". A box of rice is more specific than just a box; it's a way to specify a kind of box. But with "plupart", the rice already exists and can be referred to with the definite article -- some of it is just being referred to specifically.

Comment: Could you expand just a little by providing other examples of things that fall into each category? Like other words that act like *beaucoup* here and other words that act like *plupart* here?

Comment: "_Plupart_" probably comes from something like "_plus de parties (de qqch)_", which would underscore the idea of counting fractions of time in "_plupart_".

Comment: @Aerovistae Like *beaucoup de* in this regard: *plus de*, *moins de*, *peu de*, *trop de*. Like *la plupart de* in this regard: *la majorité de*, *la plus grande partie de*, *un grand nombre de*.

Comment: @LukeSawczak That's right, except for "*un grand nombre de*" which acts like *beaucoup de*, not *la plupart de*. Also, it can't be used with *temps*. I'll add that you can construct lots of phrases with *partie*, i.e. *une petite partie de*, *la majeure partie de*, etc.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Good point -- *un grand nombre de* can actually have either meaning. A careful look at the subtle difference between "un grand nombre d'enfants" (first time the children are mentioned) and "un grand nombre des enfants" (we've heard of these children before or they're about to be specified with a relative clause) would be a good bit of practice for the asker!